# Want to add Edit "Page # of #" footer in CRYSTAL REPORT

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, formula-editor

New to Crystal Reports. 
Trying to add the Following text to the footer of Crystal Report
Text "Shipment" + "(pg.)N of M
without having the word "Page" in the footer

Answer (score 0):

Suppress Formula field.
Check "Suppress Blank Section"
Check "Clamp Page Footer"

Comment: Hello! I can't find "Clamp Page Footer" . I am using Crystal Reports 2011